# Django update boolean field with a form

Tags: django, forms

My simple web-application has two models that are linked (one to many).

The first model (`Newplate`) has a boolean field called `plate_complete`. This is set to `False` (0) at the start.

questions:

1. In a html page, I am trying to build a form and button that when pressed sets the above field to `True`. At the moment when I click the button the page refreshes but there is no change to the database  (`plate_complete` is still `False`). How do I do this?
2. Ideally, once the button is pressed I would also like to re-direct the user to another webpage (`readplates.html`). This webpage does not require the pk field (but the form does to change the specific record) Hence for now I am just refreshing the `extendingplates.html` file. How do I do this too ?

My code:

```
"""Model"""
class NewPlate(models.Model):
    plate_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    plate_complete = models.BooleanField()

"""view"""
def publish_plates(request,plate_id):
    newplate = get_object_or_404(NewPlate, pk=plate_id)
    newplate.plate_complete = True
    newplate.save()

    #2nd method
    NewPlate.objects.filter(pk=plate_id).update(plate_complete = True)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('tablet:extendplates', args=[plate_id]))




"""URLS"""
       path('readplates', views.read_plates, name='readplates'),
       path('extendplates/<pk>/', views.show_plates, name='showplates'),
       path('extendplates/<pk>/', views.publish_plates, name='publishplates'),

"""HTML"""
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'tablet:publishplates' newplate.plate_id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="button" value='True'>Publish</button></form>   

-------Added show plates view:---------

def show_plates(request,pk):
    mod = NewPlate.objects.all()
    newplate= get_object_or_404(mod, pk=pk)
    add2plate= Add2Plate.objects.filter(Add2Plateid=pk)
    return render(request, 'tablet/show_plates.html', {'newplate': newplate,'add2plate': add2plate})
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is two of your urls have the same pattern `'extendplates/<pk>/'`. Django uses the first pattern that matches a url. I suppose that one of these view `views.show_plates` is meant to display the form and the other `views.publish_plates` is meant to accept the posted form data.

This means that simply both of these views should simply be a **single** view (to differentiate if the form is submitted we will simply check the requests method):

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render


def show_plates(request, plate_id):
    newplate = get_object_or_404(NewPlate, pk=plate_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        newplate.plate_complete = True
        newplate.save()
        return redirect('tablet:extendplates', plate_id)
    context = {'newplate': newplate}
    return render(request, 'your_template_name.html', context)
```

Now your url patterns can simply be (Note: Also captured arguments are passed as keyword arguments to the view so they should be consistent for your view and pattern):

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('readplates', views.read_plates, name='readplates'),
    path('extendplates/<uuid:plate_id>/', views.show_plates, name='showplates'),
    ...
]
```

In your form simply forego the action attribute as it is on the same page:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="button" value='True'>Publish</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes!  This is very helpful thank you. I have been chasing my own tail on this I'm going over this now but I think you have solved this. Will send an update later.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid changing state on a get request like your view does currently.

Handle the `POST` request and change the data if the request is valid (ensuring CSRF protection).

```
def publish_plates(request,plate_id):
    newplate = get_object_or_404(NewPlate, pk=plate_id)

    if request.method == "POST":
        newplate.plate_complete = True
        newplate.save(update_fields=['plate_complete'])  # a more efficient save

        #2nd method
        NewPlate.objects.filter(pk=plate_id).update(plate_complete=True)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('tablet:extendplates', args=[plate_id]))
```

You could also put a hidden input in the form, or make a form in Django to hold the hidden input, which stores the `plate_id` value and that way you can have a generic URL which will fetch that ID from the `POST` data.

Now the real problem you've got here, is that you've got 2 URLs which are the same, but with 2 different views.

I'd suggest you change that so that URLs are unique;

```
       path('extendplates/<pk>/', views.show_plates, name='showplates'),
       path('publish-plates/<pk>/', views.publish_plates, name='publishplates'),
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So I understand the URLs should be unique I will change this. What I am really looking to do is click the 'form button'  the boolean filed changes to true and it redirects me to another page.

Comment: @JackGowan you could also use the `update_fields` kwarg on saving to be more efficient given that you're just changing that 1 field.